# how to reduce time complexity of the following code

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, multidimensional-array, time-complexity

Can anyone explain how can I reduce the time complexity of this code which finds the maximum number from 2-d array

```
mat = [[17, 2, 33, 4],
               [25, 66, 7, 8],
               [9, 10, 78, 12],
               [13, 14, 15, 16]]
    import sys
    max = -sys.maxsize - 1
    N = 4
    M = 4
    
    for i in range(N):
      for j in range(M):
        if (mat[i][j] > max):
          max = mat[i][j]
    
    print(max)
```

Comment: The code is optimal with respect to time complexity. If you want fast matrices and matrix operations, perhaps you should check out numpy.

Comment: Please refrain from posting homework questions.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot reduce the complexity in means of `O`-Notation, because you need to read at least all the input. So no algorithm can be of lower complexity than `O(N*M)` (Where N, M are the dimensions of the matrix)

Comment: YOU mean this is already optimized? I dont think so

Comment: @joyealex Why not? Unless you have some other specification on the array (e.g. sorted in some way), you have do to a full scan to find the maximum; no way to reduce under MxN.

Comment: @joye alex: Optimal complexity does not mean that it  cannot be optimized any further! But you can just gain a linear factor (at most).

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of finding the maximum is O(n), like in your code.
But you can reduce the execution time by using builtin-functions:

```
from itertools import chain

mat = [[17, 2, 33, 4],
       [25, 66, 7, 8],
       [9, 10, 78, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16]]

maximum = max(chain.from_iterable(mat))
```

Comment: could you please explain how will the execution time imporve on using itertools ?

Comment: your solution is giving this error TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-29-6af628bad841> in <module>() 6 [13, 14, 15, 16]] 7 ----> 8 maximum = max(chain.from_iterable(mat)) TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: You have overwritten the built-in `max`-function with a number. Be careful when using builtin names as variables.

Comment: it is giving the same error even after re-namig the variable name

Comment: i am using this now and still getting the same error:::::::  mat = [[17, 2, 33, 4],
           [25, 66, 7, 8],
           [9, 10, 78, 12],
           [13, 14, 15, 16]]

import sys
max1 = -sys.maxsize - 1
N = 4
M = 4

for i in range(N):
  for j in range(M):
    if (mat[i][j] > max1):
      max1 = mat[i][j]

print(max1)



from itertools import chain

mat = [[17, 2, 33, 4],
       [25, 66, 7, 8],
       [9, 10, 78, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16]]

maximum = max(chain.from_iterable(mat))

Comment: can you first run code and write it here so that i may not get any error. will be highly grateful if you do so

Comment: @joyealex: you are producing the error, by overwritting the `max`-function. Restart your notebook and don't use `max` as variable in any place.

Comment: O(n) is not the time complexity but O(NxM) is, even in this case. No way to overcome the fact that you **need** to parse the entire matrix, thus N*M elements.